# Python csv.reader automatically converting ISO dates?

Tags: python, date, csv, iso

I'm using Python's csv.reader to bring a set of dates & coordinates from a file into a list. Here's a sample line from the .csv and the code:

> 2012-05-06,2012-05-13,165,35.20068,-89.79318

```
    with open('innovation.csv', 'rb') as f:
       reader = csv.reader(f)
       for row in reader:
         parseMe.append(row)
```

The problem is that for some reason, when the date is put into the list, the string is being changed from an ISO format to a calendar format:

> ['5/6/2012', '5/13/2012', '35.20068', '-89.79318']

Any thoughts on what is happening here? Is it something csv.reader that is changing the strings? What can I do to prevent it or change it back to the ISO format?

Comment: `csv.reader` is not changing anything.  The file you think is being opened is probably not the same as the file that is actually being opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`csv.reader` is not changing anything. The file you think is being opened is probably not the same as the file that is actually being opened.

To prove this run:

```
with open('innovation.csv', 'r') as f:
    print f.read()
```

The most likely cause of this is that the `'inovation.csv'` file you are looking at is in a different directory than the `'inovation.csv'` that your program is opening.

Comment: Total noob mistake. Steven was spot on. I forgot that I re-ran the innovation.csv file, but forgot to change the date format from the original data list. That also explains the missing "165".

Thanks so very much for the quick replies!

Answer (score 1):

Just ran a quick test in Python 2.7.3 (if you get different results, please say what version you're using as this may be a "feature" or bug in different version).

```
data = "2012-05-06,2012-05-13,165,35.20068,-89.79318\n2012-05-06,2012-05-13,165,35.20068,-89.79318\n"
import csv
import StringIO
infile = StringIO.StringIO(data)
reader = csv.reader(infile)
for row in reader:
    print row
```

Output to confirm that csv isn't doing anything to the dates:

```
['2012-05-06', '2012-05-13', '165', '35.20068', '-89.79318']
['2012-05-06', '2012-05-13', '165', '35.20068', '-89.79318']
```

csv is basically just doing a string.split(',') (at least on this simple input) it's not doing any other processing of the data.  I'm also noticing that your output is missing the '165' data from my tests, is ParseMe doing something internal other than just appending rows?

Comment: Thanks, John. It was much simpler: I was using an older file in a different directory. Thanks for the help, though!